# Create JSON from SQL based on Swagger model

Tags: c#, sql, json, model, swagger

Not sure I am approaching this in the right way.

I have some data in SQL and need to produce som JSON based on some of the colums and POST them to an API.
The API uses Open API and swagger so I can see what the JSON should look like in the swagger example.

I am thinking about if I should create models based on the example json (https://json2csharp.com/) and then if it is possible to produce my json with correct values using a model class...or should I just create the json manually using e,g JArray...

hope I made myself clear and that someone can point me to a good resource for this.

Comment: Are you talking about serializing the model / object you get from sql?

Comment: Maybe.  At least some of the columns. And the JSON should have a structure as the swagger example/mode Not as the sql model.